# Python; Selenium find_elements error

Tags: python, selenium

Currently webscraping soundcloud, using the selenium library. I'm trying to view everything contained in the "sc-visuallyhidden" class but the .text() function only work on find_element and not find_elements. Any suggestions?

```
search = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.sc-visuallyhidden')
print(search.text)
```

This returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_elements` method returns a list of elements. You can loop through each of them and print the text

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.sc-visuallyhidden')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```